# Wireshark: Sniffing packets from network 1 hop away

Tags: wireshark

In my home network, I have connected ISP's line at my first router (R1). Then, connected second router (R2) with the first router. LAN port of R1 and WAN port of R2 has wired connection. I have my computer connected with R2. Is it possible to sniff packets of R1 using Wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no, it should not be possible, as the R1 router would have to be incorrectly sending packets to R2, and R2 would then have to be incorrectly forwarding those packets out to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark works in promiscuous mode and can only sniff packets that pass it's network interface and your router won't be passing R1 traffic to R2.